# keycloak: scope is empty besides of requesting for that

Tags: keycloak

Currently, I'm getting this JWT token:

```
{
  "exp": 1682513368,
  "iat": 1682513308,
  "jti": "5b685309-dd70-46da-bee5-95fa61ffa01e",
  "iss": "http://keycloak-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/realms/master",
  "sub": "a5c6c027-63b0-4f99-92d1-859b92cf3617",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "RDOCUI",
  "acr": "1",
  "scope": "",
  "clientHost": "10.49.88.118",
  "clientId": "RDOCUI",
  "clientAddress": "10.49.88.118"
}
```

As you can see, `"scope": ""`. `scope` field is empty.

I've configure my client with this client scope:

[image]

This client scope is configured with a mapper adding audience.

Why both are empty, if I'm requesting for "scope=backoffice"?

My call:

```
$ http --body --form POST $KEYCLOAK/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token 'client_id=RDOCUI' "client_secret=$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET" 'grant_type=client_credentials' scope==backoffice
```

And response:

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJlQXFqWklrd3JMZ3p4N2JJMHBqbEJfNUhvSlFWOUtsRU5zUWtyQXZkSDdJIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2ODI1MTQwMTIsImlhdCI6MTY4MjUxMzk1MiwianRpIjoiZjFkNjliZGQtMzExMy00ZGE0LWI0ZWMtZjExYWIyNzI5ZmUzIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2tleWNsb2FrLWVzcGFpZG9jLXRyYW5zdmVyc2FsLmFwcHMub2NwZGVzLnQtc3lzdGVtcy5lcy9yZWFsbXMvbWFzdGVyIiwic3ViIjoiYTVjNmMwMjctNjNiMC00Zjk5LTkyZDEtODU5YjkyY2YzNjE3IiwidHlwIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwiYXpwIjoiUkRPQ1VJIiwiYWNyIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlIjoiIiwiY2xpZW50SG9zdCI6IjEwLjQ5Ljg4LjExOCIsImNsaWVudElkIjoiUkRPQ1VJIiwiY2xpZW50QWRkcmVzcyI6IjEwLjQ5Ljg4LjExOCJ9.H5JI_z73k8wKLPwrN70_poxMZj1gBqbN8fNx8M8r836_Ter-b2izv_e5kjmALT1oegPag7x9sU1bpQT41KAHWvSM_tn3KjAJUIiul4dxLodPTeXIXmS4_rpN3ydt-hBdjgQ5NXju_9YRfM2Zm8Rty2UgbHyUji_I3rZVcAZ7hWsxplJCixmz4qQ68QNu898FLxpyxm-hkmP14fRfqcnfStap9SC-gzOjY8mhp63QxK9HmhGow2GHUrI9KALj-zifXmLT8_RWTXU1y8VacbjgQp4OlWt88AVhlKNNUfSfnBiD6U9pwbQC9SpO0Xk4Ufq6GFla8BbUtOlBRRaA_fmpFA","expires_in":60,"refresh_expires_in":0,"token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":0,"scope":""}
```

Any ideas?